# Enabling correct view updates in a custom SwiftUI container view

Tags: swiftui

The traditional way of creating a custom SwiftUI container is to simply declare a `var content: () -> Content` property inside a custom `: View` struct. We can then call the content function inside the container view's `body` to place the contained content.

This generally works, but there are situations where this fails. In the following simple scenario, view updates stop working reliably.

We also notice that if we replace our custom container with a native container such as `HStack`, the updates work correctly, implying that native containers come with something extra that allows the updates to trigger. It is unclear what is missing:

```swift
struct Container<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        self.content()
    }
}

struct Screen: View {
    // [1]
    // @State
    @AppStorage("isOn")
    private var isOn = false

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle("Outside", isOn: self.$isOn)

            Container {
                Toggle("Container", isOn: self.$isOn)
            }
            // [2]
            HStack {
                Toggle("HStack", isOn: self.$isOn)
            }
        }
        // [3]
        // .toggleStyle(MyToggleStyle())
    }
}

public struct MyToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
    public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        Button {
            configuration.isOn.toggle()
        } label: {
            configuration.label

            Text(configuration.isMixed ? "Mixed" : configuration.isOn ? "On" : "Off")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    Screen()
}
```

We make a few observations (see annotations in the code):

1. If we use `@State` to track the state of `isOn`, all view updates trigger correctly. However, with `@AppStorage`, they do not.
2. The native `HStack` container does not suffer from any view update issues while the custom `Container` view does.
3. When we specify a custom `ToggleStyle`, the view updates further degrade, causing the content view to stop updating even when interacted with directly.

Can anyone advise how to implement a correct custom SwiftUI container view which behaves akin to the native ones regarding view updates?

Comment: I highly suspect this is a bug with `AppStorage`. If you wrap the `Toggle("Container", isOn: self.$isOn)` into its own view, passing the `Binding`. It works too.

Comment: @Sweeper I suspect that is because in such a case, the view updates are being handled by your new view, rather than by the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing in `T: View`, it is recommended to evaluate the closure before storing it. When you do this, it stays in sync in all the examples that you listed:

```
struct Container<Content: View>: View {
    var content: Content

    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        self.content
    }
}
```

*Note: this was mentioned in the SwiftUI WWDC Labs by SwiftUI engineers, but unfortunately, Apple doesn't publish that content after WWDC and it remains at best in the walled garden of the Slack and at worst, lost to time. I'm looking for a link that backs up my claim.*

Comment: Huh. So the fact that using `@State` works is a mere coincidence? This also means that one would have to hand-write a lot of initialisers, not being able to use the automatically generated memberwise initialiser. :(

Comment: Thanks! You are on to something. Presumably, when the contained view is resolved during init of the container, it is done so under the supervision of the contained (parent) view, which is the one that owns `@AppStorage`, while left as a closure, the view resolution happens inside the container's body.
We can also use `struct Container<Content: View>: View { @ViewBuilder let content: Content`, so an `init` is unnecessary.
If you can track down that information, would be fantastic.